# how to throw and catch web api exception?

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api

I am trowing Exception from WebApi as shown below

```
Catch(ex)
{
var rEx =     HttpResponseException(r.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,ex));
      throw rEx;
}
```

My question is "How to catch this Exception in Windows Application";
i.e. to catch this exception from where I am calling Web Api Method????

Comment: How does the application call the WebAPI method?  Did you try wrapping that call in a `try/catch`?

Answer (score 0):

You will receive response with http code 500 - internal server code. So, to "catch" this exception just check response code in calling app.

Answer (score 0):

That would throw a 404 response back to the client. Assuming you're using WebClient to call this service, it can be done in a couple of ways:

1) You can check for the status of the response like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
       //write app code.
}
```

2) Or.. in a try/catch fashion by checking: resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(), which would throw an exception if the response is not 200. Like this:

```
try
{
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
  resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();    // Throw if not a success code.

   // ...
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
// Handle exception.
}
```

It is discussed in detail [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)